# WCF - Oracle db - android

Tags: android, oracle, visual-studio, wcf

I'm trying to create a WCF (web service) in order to connect a oracle data base server and use it on a android app. Could someone tell me which language is the best in order to create a WCF? I know visual basic .Net is good for it. Is there other langague for it? And could someone show me a good tutorial in order to create this WCF? I don't want to create a ASMX, I think WCF is better.
Please Help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether categorizing one vs. other as best is the right way to think about it. There is a ton of code out there written in both languages. Personally and because of my background - I use c# and all the .NET jobs I've had over the years have required c# knowledge and not VB.NET.

That being said - you can implement a WCF service in either language.
I'm sure you have investigated what WCF is. If not - you can start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx

The following tutorial should get you started:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wcf/

You will need a .NET library that allows you to connect to an Oracle Database. One that I've used is the Oracle Data Provider for .NET which is from Oracle.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much. I'll take a look on the links. That helps me a lot.

Comment: Great. Please mark the answer accepted if it answers your question / helped you as others may find it useful as well.